# Put LinearGradient in front of Widget using ShaderMask

Tags: flutter

I am trying to achieve this in Flutter:

[image: Scrim example]

So I made this `StatelessWidget`:

```dart
class Scrim extends StatelessWidget {
  Scrim({
    @required this.child
  });

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
        return LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: [Colors.black45, Colors.transparent],
        ).createShader(bounds);
      },
      blendMode: BlendMode.darken,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

But I can't find a `blendMode` to make it look in the way that I want. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that effect you have to use `Stack` widget. `Stack` has a children property which is just a bunch of widgets to stack on top of each other.

So you'd have:

Stack

- Image
- GradientOverlay

AFAIK it's not possible to use `ShaderMask` for what you want.

Comment: I actually made with a `Container` and a `BoxDecoration` with a `LinearGradient`, I don't know of any `GradientOverlay` class in Flutter. But I was trying with `ShaderMask` because I was advised so.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant -> Image = BoxDecoration, GradientOverlay = LinearGradient. Glad it works!